# sed + delete lines that contain string except lines with

Tags: linux, awk, sed

This sed command delete  lines that contain the word 'rocommunity':

```
sed -i '/rocommunity/d' snmpd.conf

rocommunity hedona 127.0.0.1
rocommunity hedona linux1 
rocommunity hedona linux12
rocommunity hedona linux13
rocommunity hedona linux15
rocommunity hedona linux16
rocommunity hedona linux17
syscontact linux 67
syslocation UNKNOWN
trapcommunity hedona
trapsink  linux76 parshedona
```

How to update my sed in order to delete  lines that contain rocommunity, except the line with 127.0.0.1

expected output:

```
rocommunity hedona 127.0.0.1
syscontact linux 67
syslocation UNKNOWN
trapcommunity hedona
trapsink  linux76 parshedona
```

Comment: `sed -i '/127\.0\.0\.1/b;/rocommunity/d' snmpd.conf`

Answer (score 5):

Simply combine two searches:

```
sed  '/rocommunity.*127\.0\.0\.1/p;/rocommunity/d' /path/to/input
```

`/rocommunity.*127\.0\.0\.1/p` - On a line with a match for `rocommunity` followed by a match for `127.0.0.1`, print the line

`/rocommunity/d` - On a line with a match for `rocommunity`, do not print

Everything else will be printed.

To change file file once you've confirmed what you want is what is being done, you can use `sed --in-place` to make the changes to the file.

Comment: You're avoiding the "double negative" in my solution with that `sed`. Neat.

Comment: Interestingly, that's what my first draft did, but it was bugging me for being too indirect.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -n -e '/rocommunity.*127.0.0.1/p' -e '/rocommunity/!p' data.in >data.out
```

The `sed` command first of all turns off the default printing of every line (`-n`) and then uses two editing commands (`-e`). The first one will print any line that contians the word `rocommunity` followed by `127.0.0.1` later on the line. The second editing command will print all lines not containing `rocommunity`.

With the data in the beginning of your question:

```
$ sed -n -e '/rocommunity.*127.0.0.1/p' -e '/rocommunity/!p' data.in
rocommunity hedona 127.0.0.1
syscontact linux 67
syslocation UNKNOWN
trapcommunity hedona
trapsink  linux76 parshedona
```

Comment: Amusingly, I revised my original answer to match yours before yours appeared.  Great minds something something.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Ah. But there are minor differences still. It's a matter of taste whether one uses `;` to separate editing commands (your way), or multiple `-e` (my way).

Comment: Indeed.  For more complex operations, I will opt to break them out, but for a simple thing like this, I tend to stitch them together.

Answer (score 1):

if matched "rocommunity" and "127.0.0.1" then branch to end.
and will print the line.

```
sed -e '/rocommunity{/127\.0\.0\.1/b' -e 'd;}' file
```

Which with the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can shorten to:

```
sed '/rocommunity/{/127\.0\.0\.1/b;d}' file
```

Comment: Explaining what this command does would significantly improve the quality of the answer. You can [edit] your post.